# Git save file then stop tracking

Tags: git

I want to store a datafile in my project, which stores a default password. I want to then stop tracking it in git, and change the dummy values to real values. I expect that subsequently, when I push, that my changed file will remain the same, and hopefully when I pull too.

```
$ echo generic > mysecret.txt
$ git add mysecret.txt
$ git commit -m "added a generic data to the secret file"
$ echo "mysecret.txt" >> .gitignore
$ echo secret > mysecret.txt
```

Hopefully, after that my password will be safe (although I am pretty sure it is not, so am asking for advice here)

How should I better handle this problem?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `git update-index --assume-unchanged <path/to/file>` after you replaced the dummy values with the real values.